Завышены и завышенны
Для меня является странным делом, что в Орфографическом академическом словаре РАН слово "завышенный" в кратких формах имеет лишь одну "н".

Я считаю это определенной ошибкой, потому как у слова «завышенный», в отличие от слов-родственников (повышенный, превышенный и т.п.), существует свое устойчивое значение: «нереальный, слишком высокий». Например, тогда, когда мы характеризуем абстрактный объект, мы имеем в виду именно это значение: требования явно завышеННы и недопустимы; ожидания слишком завышеННы, даже нереальны  (ни ожидания, ни требования никто не завышал, они сами по себе такие), в то время как для вещественных объектов больше подходит причастное значение: оценка завышеНа, цена завышеНа (и цену, и оценку завысили, что понятно и без уточнений).

Кто-то может сказать, почему была установлена такая норма?

Я даю подробное решение задачи и надеюсь, что материал будет полезен для всех пользователей языка.
ТЕОРИЯ
Правило известное, оно есть у Розенталя и в ПАС:  Розенталь §48, пункт 7 и 8; ПАС под ред.Лопатина § 102.
Смысл в том, что некоторые причастия могут образовывать прилагательные с качественным (переносным) значением, и тогда в краткой форме пишется Н для причастий  и НН для прилагательных, например: Тучи рассеяны (ветром). — Она очень рассеянна.
Но дело в том, что  прилагательные в краткой форме иногда  ведут себя как причастия, и тогда пишется Н.
А какие прилагательные?  Есть три варианта, которые нужно хорошо различать и контролировать по Русскому орфографическому словарю РАН на сайте Грамота.ру,  иначе ошибиться очень просто.
  Прилагательные 1 (НН)
  Русский орфографический словарь: рассеянный; кр. ф. прич. 
 -ян, -яна; кр. ф. прил. (невнимательный) -ян, -янна.

  Прилагательные 2 (Н)
  Русский орфографический словарь: заплаканный; кр. ф. -ан, 
  -ана; заржавленный; кр. ф. -ен, -ена.

  Прилагательные 3 (Н и НН)
  Русский орфографический словарь: насыщенный; кр. ф. прич. 
 -ен, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (с дополн.: жизнь 
  насыщена приключениями) и -ен, -енна (без дополн.: жизнь 
  насыщенна, содержательна).

Подробнее описание групп в статье https://proza.ru/2022/12/10/1768
РЕШЕНИЕ
Для слова завышенный есть собственная словарная статья в значении прилагательного, а значение причастия определяем по глаголу завысить. Это (по словарю РАН)  группа 2, где для причастий и прилагательных дается  одинаковый вариант Н.
Я считаю что в качественном значении прилагательного есть элемент субъективной оценки, в то время как в причастии прямое значение: фирма с определенной целью завышает цены по сравнению с обычными нормами и т.д.
СЛОВАРИ
 ЗАВЫШЕННЫЙ
 Русский орфографический словарь
 завышенный; кр. ф. -ен, -ена

 Большой толковый словарь русского языка
 ЗАВЫШЕННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -шен, -шена, -шено. Превышающий 
 реально возможные или заслуженные нормы, оценки, объём и 
 т.п. какой-л. деятельности или её результатов. З. план. З- 
 ые показатели. З-ые требования, претензии. З-ая оценка. 
 Завышенность, -и; ж.

 ЗАВЫСИТЬ
 Большой толковый словарь русского языка
 ЗАВЫСИТЬ, -вышу, -высишь; завышенный; -шен, -а, -о; св. 
 что. Повысить сверх реально возможного или заслуженного (о 
 размерах, количественных показателях какой-л. деятельности 
 и т.п.; противоп.: занизить). З. оценки на экзамене. З. 
 нормы. З. цены. З. план. Завышать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. 
 Завышаться, -ается; страд. Завышение, -я; ср. З. средних 
  показателей.

Еще интересный пример для группы 3, где в причастиях пишем Н, а для прилагательных две нормы Н и НН в зависимости от наличия дополнения. Ситуацию можно назвать "Орфографические войны", где трое против одного. И парадоксальный результат — ответ принят именно у одного.  Но это уже тема из психологии)

А почему именно так-то? Почему не "нн",а  "н" решили нормировать?

У причастия общее правило – Н для всех случаев. А значение прилагательного по сути переносное, производное. Еще пример: ножи заржавлены, глаза заплаканы,  причастие не может образоваться от непереходного глагола.  И когда прилагательное реагирует на зависимое дополнение, оно похоже на причастие, а не наоборот.

Не понимаю, о каком дополнении идет речь, ведь его здесь нет: "завышенные требования". Требования (какие) завышенные. Завысить (кого, что) требования. Глагол переходный.

Просто "требования завышены организаторами" и "требования завышенны" явно не одно и то же.

У вас нет дополнения, глагол переходный. Но я в общем отвечаю на ваш вопрос про три варианта при коррекции Н/НН. И на этот вопрос я уже ответила: у вас причастие и прилагательное, по семантике они различны,  но прилагательное ВЕДЕТ себя как причастие, поэтому пишется Н.  // Я считаю, что в общем случае учитывается наличие производителя действия: у причастия это сама фирма, а у прилагательного – пользователи с их субъективным мнением. Это если объяснять решение (мое мнение, а вы можете истолковать иначе).  // Но закон есть закон, писать надо по словарю РАН, чтобы оставаться в пределах нормы.

Сравните: Цены завышены  торговой фирмой.   Цены завышены  торговой фирмой, по мнению пользователей.  Есть же разница в сообщениях, а производитель действия один и тот же (форма Т.п.) И это признак причастия.  Прилагательное ведет себя как причастие.

Для меня тут одинаковые значения причастий.

Тогда предлагаю вам найти собственное объяснение для решения РАН,
уж они-то знают)  Или задайте вопрос Справочной службе. Вероятно,  подобные вопросы нужно задавать специалистам, работающим над словарем.  Я же могла объяснить, как пользоваться словарем РАН и ответила на ваш вопрос, когда была установлена норма. Об этом говорил еще Розенталь, так что информация не новая. Но объяснения для этого слова он не привел.

Кстати, можно проверить прилагательное по другим показателям. К прмиеру, у него нет сравнительной степени. Не образцовое такое прилагательное. Да и на слух едва отличается от причастия. Форма НН ему просто не к лицу, странно выглядит.

Хорошо. А что, например, со словом "зашоренный" не так? Краткая форма тоже с "н", однако форма "зашоренней" существует.
