Диктант «О неуверенности»: Как правильно: (не) увер(нн)ые в выборе; (не) увере(нн)ы в выборе?
Вы можете проверить свои знания по этой теме. Можно написать текст по слуху, но еще интереснее проверить его по правилам. Для этого в каждом случае (хотя бы для себя) определите статус слова (прилагательное или причастие) и вспомните нужное правило. Но для ответа можно просто правильно записать текст.
Выбираем форму написания НЕ и Н/НН для прилагательных уверенный и неуверенный.
ДИАЛОГ
— Она (не)увере(нн)ый в себе человек, (не)увере(нн)ый в своих решениях, постоянно сомневается.
— Ну да, застенчива, (не)увере(нн)а  —  это про нее.  В то же время сомневаться — это нормально. (Не)увере(нн)ый, а всегда сомневающийся — это вроде бы про ученых и гениев.
— Но она (не)увере(нн)а ни в чем и прежде всего (не)увере(нн)а в себе. И даже голос (не)увере(нн)ый. Иногда замолчит, (не)увере(нн)ая в том, что стоит говорить дальше.
— Не все увере(нн)ы в своей правоте,  даже в мелочах. (Не)увере(нн)ые  в действительно сложном, начинают сомневаться и в незначительном.
Дополнительный вопрос: Какие правила регулируют тему?
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ  от 28.07.2024 (комментарий к уже данному ответу)
Если точнее, как вы определяете статус прилагательное/причастие, чтобы применить нужное правило.  К примеру, при наличии придаточного у нас причастие или прилагательное? В чем признак по действию для причастия "они не уверены, что...". А если это ВСЕГДА прилагательное, то почему раздельное написание НЕ. Какое правило здесь действует?
Словарь РАН хорошо разобрался с Н/НН для кратких форм, а вот для НЕ такой ясности нет.
P. S. А это статья в качестве приложения к теме: Почему умные люди полны сомнений, а некомпетентные так уверены в себе?

Нужно руководствоваться орфографическим словарем Лопатина.
уверенный; кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (с дополн.: она уверена в своей правоте) и -ен, -енна (без дополн.: она спокойна и уверенна; движения её уверенны); будь уверена, будьте уверены (не сомневайся, не сомневайтесь).
Что касается слитного и раздельного написания, то здесь действует обычное правило. При наличии слов отнюдь, вовсе, далеко, отрицательных местоимений, а также при отрицании, частица  не пишется раздельно.

Спасибо, Серж, а где же диктант с правильными ответами. Это ведь ВИШЕНКА НА ТОРТЕ.  // И как отличить прилагательное от причастия, ведь правила в этих случаях принципиально разные.  У причастия  НЕ раздельно, в краткой форме только Н.  У прилагательного обе формы: НЕ слитно и раздельно, Н и НН в КРАТКОЙ форме. // И прямой вопрос:  Из словаря РАН:  Неуверенный в правильности решения.  Это ведь прилагательное?  Поэтому  зависимое слово не  влияет на слитное написание НЕ. А в Карте слов  в большинстве случаев раздельное написание. Почему?

Мне на этот вопрос никто не ответил в теме https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/481201/Так-всё-же-неуверенный-в-себе-или-не-уверенный-в-себе.    Мой ответ там сейчас краткий и исправленный. Тогда, пожалуйста, напишите диктант.

А где сам диктант?

Как где?))   В моем вопросе, где надо все скобки раскрыть.  И еще в вопрос я текст добавила (о правилах).

На подобный вопрос отвечал институт русского языка Виноградова. Могу послать вам на почту, если интересно.

Именно для этих слов? Мне интересно, пошлите на почту, если она у вас есть.  А здесь нельзя опубликовать, пусть и остальные почитают.

Можно. Нет, не этих слов. А именно о разграничении отглагольных прилагательных от кратких причастий. Поэтому не опубликовал здесь, не знаю, насколько правильно будет публиковать здесь.PS.   Отправил.

Спасибо, Серж. Насколько я поняла,  на орфографическом ресурсе "Академос"  в 2023 году опубликовано правило, о котором еще мало кто знает:  "Буквы н или нн в кратких формах отглагольных слов на -нный (причастиях и прилагательных)"  По нему вносятся изменения в словарь.  Что здесь принципиально нового?  Для меня на практике это ничего не меняет - по-прежнему есть слова, которые нужно контролировать по словарю, если в их написании замечены разногласия.  Но в правилах, вероятно, объясняется выбор решения, которое обозначено в словаре.

Правило это в прямом доступе, желающие могут ознакомиться.  Можно, конечно,опубликовать ссылку, но я пока не готова давать по этому правилу объяснение. // В моей теме меня больше интересовало написание НЕ для тех слов, которые связаны с этим правилом Н/НН, а именно есть ли какое-нибудь соответствие. // Но все так сложно, что лучше оставить пока тему, тем более что она мало кому интересна.  Спасибо!

А почему возникли сомнения с этим словом? Здесь ведь явно прилагательное.

С Н/НН у меня нет сомнений, но почему НЕ в полной форме при наличии завис. слова пишут слитно в словаре, но раздельно на практике.  Посмотрите мое решение, есть у вас замечания?

Шарон, видимо, путают с причастием с зависимыми словами. Трудно сказать.

С решением согласен.

Ответ на вопрос
ДИАЛОГ
— Она неуверенный в себе человек, неуверенный в своих решениях, постоянно сомневается.
— Ну да, застенчива, неуверенна — это про нее. В то же время сомневаться — это нормально. Не уверенный, а всегда сомневающийся — это вроде бы про ученых и гениев.
— Но она не уверена ни в чем и прежде всего не уверена в себе. И даже голос неуверенный. Иногда замолчит, неуверенная  в том, что стоит говорить дальше.
— Не все уверены в своей правоте, даже в мелочах. Неуверенные в действительно сложном, начинают сомневаться и в незначительном.
Пояснение
По словарю РАН
Это прилагательное. В полной форме слово подчиняется обычным правилам для прилагательных: пишутся две НН, зависимые слова не меняют форму написания НЕ. Раздельное написание НЕ возможно при противопоставлении и усилении отрицания.
В краткой форме слово ведет себя двойственно: (1)  как прилагательное (слитное написание НЕ, две НН) при наличии однородных прилагательных , наречий степени и (2) как причастие при наличии зависимых слов (раздельное написание НЕ, одна Н).
МАТЕРИАЛЫ
 НЕУВЕРЕННЫЙ
 Русский орфографический словарь
 неуверенный*; кр. ф. -ен, -енна, прил.

 Большой толковый словарь русского языка
 НЕУВЕРЕННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -рен, -ренна, -ренно. 1. Такой, 
 которому не свойственна уверенность в ком-, чём-л.; 
 нерешительный. Человек он был робкий, н. Н. в себе. Н. в 
 правильности решения. // Выражающий нерешительность, 
 свидетельствующий об отсутствии уверенности. Н. ответ. Он 
 подтвердил согласие неуверенным кивком. Сказать неуверенным 
 голосом. 2. Нетвёрдый, неустойчивый. Н-ая походка. Сделал 
 несколько неуверенных шагов. Неуверенно, нареч. Н. 
 отвечать, взглянуть. Чувствовать себя н. Она ходила ещё н.

 Ответы справочной службы
 Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: Неуверенный в себе 
 или Не уверенный в себе?
 При противопоставлении верно раздельное написание, без -- 
 слитное.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Орфографический академический ресурс «АКАДЕМОС».
Буквы н или нн в кратких формах отглагольных слов на -нный (причастиях и прилагательных).  Дата публикации 17 апреля 2023 г.
Мнение: Н и НН: сложное правило в этом году стало ещё сложнее?
Я так не думаю, это скорее объяснение того материала, который дается в словаре РАН для тех, кому нужно понять обоснованность этих решений. Но если не углубляться в причины, то надо просто следовать словарю в отношении тех слов, для которых наблюдается двойственность написания.
Пример обсуждения на форуме https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/481165/Завышены-и-завышенны/481180#comment525452_481180

Она не уверена в своей правоте.  Прилагательное или причастие?

Хороший вопрос)  На текущий момент я считаю, что это прилагательное, которое пишется как причастие.  А что бы ему так не писаться? Одна Н по словарю РАН, который допускает две формы Н/НН для прилагательного. А по поводу НЕ у Розенталя интересная информация. Наш милый Розенталь избегает выражений "всегда пишется однозначно". но обычно говорит "в основном". И вот интересный пример из пункта 9 https://korrektor-ru.livejournal.com/1296626.html Слишком неуверенны были люди в будущем;

Может ли вообще прилагательное "неуверенный" быть причастием? Этот вопрос я задаю в текущей теме. Но ответа на него нет. Этот вопрос я задавала недавно, отвечая https://rus.stackexchange.com/posts/481204/revisions  Потом исправила ответ, огорченная общим невниманием. Там приводила возможный пример:  "Сравним с прямым значением причастия: Не уверенный нами в правильности такого решения, он продолжал сомневаться. То есть мы не смогли его уверить".  Но это редкий случай. Сейчас  я считаю, что действия нет, но есть состояние, поэтому практически всегда  у нас прилагательное.

А вот дискуссия в Сети, 2013 год. Давно это было, давно это было,..
// Не(?)уверенный
...и я, не(?)уверенный, что смогу справиться с этим заданием, ...После моей вычитки внесли правку: писать раздельно...https://korrektor-ru.livejournal.com/1296626.html  А дальше много комментариев

Вот и считаю, что прилагательное.

Только слитно в данном случае.

Ну, вам противостоит массив пользователей, которые пишут НЕ раздельно. Попробуйте доказать, что это не так. А в каких случаях можно писать раздельно, противопоставление и усиление отрицания?  Но Розенталь более осторожен и говорит "завис. слова В ОСНОВНОМ не оказывают влияние на прилагательные". Но если мы допускаем  для прилагательных две формы Н/НН, то почему бы не допустить две формы для НЕ.  И народ сомневается, вот еще нашла в Сети:  https://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4443670-pochemu-chasto-pishut-ne-uverennyj-chto-eto-oshibka.html#reply3551530

Дело в том, что по правилам Розенталя надо писать два нн в кратком прилагательном и н в кратком причастии. И, как вы верно сказали, Розенталь указывал ,что зависимые слова не влияют на прилагательное.

Серж, как правило не влияют, но исключения возможны:    Розенталь:  Примечание 1. Раздельное написание не с прилагательным, имеющим при себе пояснительные слова, встречается: 1) при прилагательных, которые в полной и краткой форме имеют разное значение (см. ниже, п. 8), например: не готовый к выходу актёр, не склонный к простуде ребёнок;   § 66. Правописание не с именами прилагательными  https://rosental-book.ru/ortho_xvii.html#sect66
